# how can I fetch data from database in django with parameter in url?

Tags: django, url, get

** URl : **

```
path('products_filter/', views.products_filter, name='products_filter'),
```

** VIEW :**

```
def products_filter(request):
    product = request.GET.get('product')
    selling = request.GET.get('selling')
    
    products = Product.objects.filter(selling='best_seller')

    return render(request, 'product/products.html', {'products':products})
```

** TEMPLATE : **

```
<a href="/product/products_filter?product={{'carpet'|urlencode}}&selling={{'best_seller'|urlencode}}">
```

Comment: can we see your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the parameters you want to retrieve from the url to your url and make sure the url in the template adds them. For example:

urls.py:

```
path('products_filter/<str:product>/<str:selling>/', views.products_filter, name='products_filter'),
```

template:

```
<a href="{% url 'products_filter' product=carpet|urlencode selling=best_seller|urlencode %}">
```